Where is string merging syntax documented
I found this example in the documentation.
c = 3-5j
('The complex number {0} is formed from the real part {0.real} '
 'and the imaginary part {0.imag}.').format(c)

Strings can be merged in this way.
text = ("a"
'''b'''
'c'
)
print(text)
# Ouput: abc

A similar syntax is present in the C.
Where is the documentation for this syntax.

It is documented at: String literal concatenation

Multiple adjacent string or bytes literals (delimited by whitespace), possibly using different quoting conventions, are allowed, and their meaning is the same as their concatenation. Thus, "hello" 'world' is equivalent to "helloworld". This feature can be used to reduce the number of backslashes needed, to split long strings conveniently across long lines, or even to add comments to parts of strings, for example:
re.compile("[A-Za-z_]"       # letter or underscore
          "[A-Za-z0-9_]*"   # letter, digit or underscore
         )

Note that this feature is defined at the syntactical level, but implemented at compile time. The ‘+’ operator must be used to concatenate string expressions at run time. Also note that literal concatenation can use different quoting styles for each component (even mixing raw strings and triple quoted strings), and formatted string literals may be concatenated with plain string literals.

